# Visual Studio Debug Mode - Peculiar Behaviour

Tags: visual-studio, multithreading, debugging, breakpoints

In visual studio 2008 while in the debug mode when we initiate a thread and put break points inside the thread function. Visual Studio doesn't debug giving explanation that i don't have the code. Why does this happens. How to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unchecking the Just My Code option in Tools -> Options -> Debugging.